# Axure: Bulk-editing cases

Tags: prototyping, axure

Is it possible to bulk-edit cases?

For example I have a dynamic panel with several states, several of them having the same on-click case "case1". Now I want to change some aspects of this case "case1" for all instances where it is in use. Right now I would have to go through every state and every object that uses this case and edit it. Is there a way to apply the changes to all these cases at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only certain attributes that can be bulk edited, unfortunately this does not include interactions.

However the paste action for the widgets is very smart. If they are all identical then the approach I take is as follows (lets presume it's *OnClick*, which is the most commonly used interaction):

1. Choose the first component, edit the *OnClick* event until it is perfect.
2. Right mouse click the *OnClick* interaction in the properties tab for the component, and choose copy. Alternatively, select the *OnClick* interaction and use the copy keyboard shortcut (Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> MacOs:  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>)
3. Select on all the components that you wish to apply the *OnClick* interaction to.
4. Use the paste keyboard shortcut (Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> MacOs:  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>).

This will apply the initial one to all the others.

Clearing them out is a pain, you have to choose each one individually, select the *OnClick* event and press <kbd>del</kbd>.